# MySQL : writing query for relational tables for strict categories

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database

I want to write a query that will select me the questions with specific countries ONLY, so when I select questions containing country 1 and 2 show me ONLY questions that have 2 countries and those countries are 1 and 2.

I have 3 tables - questions, countries, questions_has_countries

- questions : id, question
- countries : id, name
- questions_has_countries : questions_id, countries_id

I tried :

```
SELECT q.question, q.id , c.id  
FROM questions as q, countries as c,  questions_has_countries as qhc
WHERE c.id = qhc.countries_id 
AND qhc.questions_id = q.id 
AND c.id IN (1,2) 
GROUP BY q.question
HAVING COUNT( qhc.countries_id ) = 2
```

When i use line 5 ( AND c.id IN (1,2) ) my counter stops working correctly cuz it's narrowing down the search. I know i have to rewrite it but i don't know how. Pls help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the `WHERE` clause and change the `HAVING` clause into

```
HAVING  SUM(c.id IN (1,2)) = 2 AND
        COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) = 2
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/932ab7/5)

Comment: instead of `SUM(DISTINCT c.id) = 2` i think you meant `COUNT(DISTINCT c.id) = 2` right?